# How to keep auto-sized table cells format consistent after edition/deletion of rows using UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, editmode

I have a simple table view with a unique label for the cell prototype. I have been following the recommendations in order to have proper auto-sizing cells:

- setting auto-layout constraints for the label regarding its leading, trailing, top and bottom spacing in its content view,
- setting the `rowHeight` property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`,
- providing the `estimatedRowHeight` property (set to 44),
- setting the number of lines for the label to 0.

I also have enabled the default Edit Mode which allows the reordering and deletion of rows (exactly like in the *Alarm* tab of the Apple *Clock* app).

Now, on to observed problem:

1. I provide two labels, one with a short text and a second with a longer text, so that the second row has twice the height of the first row.

[image]

2. I enter Edit Mode, and swap the position of the rows. So far, everything keeps its composure and the sizing is still correct, the longer label being in the top row.
3. When I swap the positon again to return to the original layout (short label on top and long label on bottom), the longer text is not spread over two lines in its row as it should, but turns into a one-line display with an ellipsis at the end. Moreover, the height of the cell remains the same and does not fit the now single-lined text.

[image]

And after exitting Edit Mode (compare with the first image):

[image]

I suspect that I might be missing some kind of reload operation after the moving or deletion of rows, but I did not find the relevant information. Similar sizing problems appear when deleting rows that have been previously reordered.

How to keep the cell sizing as well as the text formatting consistent after moving/deletion of rows?

Thank you very much.